# Azure Search score boosting by reverse magnitude

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

I want to perform boosting on a price field, scoring products with lower prices higher. I could not find any way to specify that.

Currently I have something like

```
let priceBoost = 
        new MagnitudeScoringFunction(
            new MagnitudeScoringParameters(
                BoostingRangeStart  = 0.0,
                BoostingRangeEnd    = 100.0,
                ShouldBoostBeyondRangeByConstant = true),
            "price",
            10.0)
```

I tried reversing the BoostingRangeStart/End but that did not work, rather resulted in a serialization error on the search.

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for AzureSearch. To answer your question, you can score products with lower prices higher if you set BoostingRangeStart to 100 and BoostingRangeEnd to 0.

It seems you have a different problem though which is the serialization error. Could you please share the details on that?

Comment: It seems like the error you're getting is not related to the 'price' field which is what you were asking about. Could you test my answer without the 'points' field so we can closed on that? Feel free to email me your full index definition at jlembicz at Microsoft dot com. I'll help you resolve the serialization problem. Feel free to post a new question about the serialization issue with azure-search tag. Please try to make your example as isolated to a specific problem as possible.

Comment: Thanks Yahnoosh for confirming how to achieve boosting on descending values. I will email you separately for the serialization issue.

Comment: The serialization issue was the result of using non-nullable primitive types in a custom model class. Azure Search treats all primitive types as nullable. However, the SDK should validate this early. I've opened an issue on GitHub to track this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/1063